# Google Analytics in PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics

I have a website that displays movieTimes. `(e.g. movieTime.php?movieID=1)`

I would like to track two things.

1. how many times movieTime.php has been visited
2. how many times movieID=1 has been visited (same goes for movieID=2, movieID=3 etc)

How should I do that?

I did the below before my `</head>` but am not getting results.

```
<!-- Google Analytics Tracking -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
            _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'MovieID', <?php echo $movieID; ?>, 1]);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
```

I have also changed my accountID property so that's not the issue. :|

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting results because of this line:

```
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
```

UA-XXXXXXXX-X needs to be replaced with the property ID.

Comment: yes i did change the property ID already. i just masked it in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using Google Analytics for this. Simply use an INSERT query to track how many times the page (and specific IDs) has been visited.

Comment: Google Analytics is much much more than just tracking HITS. It shows you Traffic Sources, Referrals, and much much more, for a simply count meter, INSERT is ok

Comment: Yes I am definitely looking at getting more out of it later but for a start just to track hits.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to push a custom variable.
If you didn't explicitly filter out the movieID parameter then the existing set up will work fine and the different URIs will show up in your Content section.